# Getting React App Production Ready with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, production

I'm pretty new to using Webpack and I am trying to get my React app done in ES6 into an acceptable production ready size. The output file is still far too large, and also React is still outputting warnings (mostly about production files).

Can anyone help me trouble shoot what should be updated in my config file?

This is what I currently have.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var PROD = JSON.parse(process.env.PROD_ENV || '0');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/App.js",
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: PROD ? [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: true }
    })
  ] : []
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of smaller tweaks you could do, too many for a single answer perhaps. I've written about the topic [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/). I think just setting `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production` through `DefinePlugin` will help quite a bit. You could also consider [using react-lite or such](http://survivejs.com/webpack/advanced-techniques/configuring-react/).

Comment: I've given up wrapping my head around webpack config and just started using [hjs-webpack](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack) which does all the things and lets me spend my time actually writing code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my list of plugins for production builds:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    minimize: true,
    compress: {
      unused: true,
      dead_code: true,
      warnings: false,
      screw_ie8: true
    },
    compressor: {
      warnings: false
    }
  })
]
```

Moreover, if you find that the application is still pretty huge, what I've used is the **Webpack bundle size analyzer** ([npm.js link](https://github.com/robertknight/webpack-bundle-size-analyzer)). It will show you the list of used dependencies sorted by size, it really helped me to analyze and throw away stuff that I didn't actually need.

Comment: Thanks! Got it down to 350k (which still seems a little large, but much better). I'll try out the size analyzer and see if it helps me prioritize decencies.